# When creating a lazy button with a frame, this is created on the upper left corner why this happen?

Tags: ios, swift, button, uibutton

I create this 'filterButton' and set it to be created on the exact position of the 'menubutton', the 'filterButton' goes directly to the upper left corner of the view.

```
lazy var filterButton: UIButton! = {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.menuButton.frame.origin.x, y: self.button.frame.origin.y, width: 45, height: 45))
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.backgroundColor = .blue
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    return button
}()
```

and when I check and print the frame of the 'filterButton' it has the value of the 'menuButton', why this is happening?.

Comment: Show all code where you're adding buttons

Comment: `filterButton` and `menuButton` (according to this code) has nothing to do with each other. so I think you haven't added the filter button to the view and you still see the `menuButton`. additionally  check if these values are correct `x: self.menuButton.frame.origin.x, y: self.button.frame.origin.y`

Comment: Both buttons are added to the view. Besides when I check the frame of 'filterButton' it has this values :
       frame = (20 592; 45 45)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following constraints where you are adding filterButton to your view

```
filterButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: menuButton.leftAnchor).isActive = true
filterButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: menuButton.topAnchor).isActive = true
filterButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: menuButton.rightAnchor).isActive = true
filterButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: menuButton.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Is it ok to have multiples 'Anchor Constraints', activating and deactivating constantly?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, when you access to the instance of filterButton, frames of `menuButton` and `button` is not correct.
You can use layout constraints or update frame of `filterButton` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not of lazy button check you `menuButton` the problem is there for that you can check this :-

```
lazy var filterButton: UIButton! = {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 200, width: 45, height: 45))
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.backgroundColor = .blue
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        return button
    }()
```

Comment: I did try this, but it was the same result it was added on the upper left corner of the main view.